# ffmpeg How to keep only some metadata tags for mp3

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to remove all metadata tags form an mp3 but keep "album" and the mp3 "cover image" how would I proceed in that case?

I would expect something like this but it doesn't work:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp3" -map_metadata -1 -map_metadata album -map_metadata "Cover (front)" -c copy output.mp3
```

I'm on Windows 11 OS

Answer (score 0):

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

f="input 4.mp3"
o="/tmp/out.mp3"
MET=(-map_metadata -1)
IFS=, read ALB <<< $(ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries format_tags=album -of csv=p=0 "$f")
MET+=(-metadata "album=$ALB")
CNT=0
while IFS=, read CMN; do
MET+=(-metadata:s:v:$CNT comment="Cover (front)")
((CNT++))
done < <(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v -show_entries stream_tags=comment -of csv=p=0 "$f")

echo "${MET[@]}"
echo -----------
ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0 -c copy "${MET[@]}" "$o" -y -hide_banner
echo -----------
ffprobe "$o" -hide_banner
echo -----------
mediainfo "$o"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm on Windows.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without a script?

Comment: try this way: `ffmpeg -i "input 3.mp3" -map 0 -c copy -metadata artist= -metadata title= -metadata date= -metadata genre= -metadata track= -metadata lyrics= -metadata lyrics-eng= -y out.mp3`, add more tags

Comment: thanks, that would work but you would have to know all the tags foreahead and I belive there are some costum tags that whoever set them up can define by himself.